# How dynamically set text of button in GridLayout?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I try to set text to my buttons, by using the value of `i` in each iteration.
As you may realize by the following code, I am unable to do so.
Could you please help me out?.

```
package com.example.sequenceofnumbers;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridLayout gl = findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) { 
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(i+""); // I can't set text in this line.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where you add your buttons into Gridlayout ??

Comment: add code like gl.setView(btn);

Comment: Where? i try, but i cant ( for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            gl.setView();
        }

Comment: try with  gl.addView(btn); not setView

Comment: i want add 16 buttons. I know i should setColumnCount(4).But i dont know how set Text to my buttons(

Comment: first try my answer

Comment: in loop for and in onCreate method

Comment: check my updated ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.example.sequenceofnumbers;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.Button; //Include this package.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridLayout gl = findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) { 
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(i+"");
            gl.addView(btn); // Add this line instead.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant set text, the compiler does not see the method: setText();

Comment: where is your button import  line?    import android.widget.Button;

Comment: Surely what i need to do? I am so sorry. I am here novice)

Comment: i press and i receive notification, Thanks u and etc, but i cant click in your answer, how to correct this?

Comment: No problem..leave it HAPPY CODING ;)